# Named parameters with Japanese characters in datastore not working

Tags: gwt, parameter-passing, datastore

I am working on a Google Web Toolkit application, and I use JPA for access to the datastore.
I just found out that the following doesn't work:

```
Query q = manager.createQuery("select x from Question x where x.name=:name");
q.setParameter("name", "ト<br />");
q.getResultList();
```

This returns 0 results.
But not using named parameters does work:

```
Query q = manager.createQuery("select x from Question x where x.name='ト<br />'");
q.getResultList();
```

This returns 2 results, which is correct. Perhaps it has to do with the kana symbol (ト), but it looks like a bug anyway. Has anyone experienced this as well, is it a known bug, or am i doing something wrong? I guess i could just avoid named parameters, but i rather not.

Edit: removed typo in example that wasn't present in my original code

Answer (score 0):

problem is encoding for binding variable.

Check encoding configuration, this aspect could depend from datastore.

bye

Comment: The rest of the application works fine with unicode, so it doesn't seem to be a problem of the datastore itself, but with the query. Is there a way to set encoding on a Query object?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this:

```
q.setParameter("name", "ト<br />");
```

?

I guess you don't need the ":" in the parameter name.

You may want to read [this doc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html).

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo on my part, my actual code didn't contain the :